# How to reduce HeapTrack generated file size?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I am running Heaptrack over a large code base to detect memory leak errors. The code runs for around 6 hours. When I tried running heaptrack over the code for 1 hour the log generated had size around 3.5 gb. Analyzing the file with heaptrack --analyze took lot of time. Is there any way to identify memory leaks over large program with a relatively smaller log file?
I've used the following commands

```
    heaptrack <executable>
    heaptrack_print -l yes -p no -a no -T no <heaptrack file>
```

I need a very fast profiler with less than 2-3 times slowdown and it should detect memory leaks. Heaptrack is very good for this purpose.